# How to access and edit files from admin panel?

Tags: theming, files

How i can acces my files without going to host control panel or by ftp. I mean if any module is for that to access and edit files from Admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try [elfinder File Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder) module, which also allows inline text file editing, besides other file managing operations.

Comment: Any documentation? I installed and enabled all module and requirement but don't know how to open a file from theme directory and edit it

Comment: Nice one, didn't know this module.

Comment: Yeah, it's the closest to what you are looking for in Drupal. Find the [documentation here](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki). And, If it solves your problem, could you kindly check my answer so it also helps other people in the future?

Answer (score 0):

The full path or under sites/foobar/files? You should try IMCE. It has a browser-client.
This is the link: https://www.drupal.org/project/imce

Comment: Can i edit the files with it? for example i want to edit my theme and need to update the css file every minute.

Comment: I have installed the IMCE module but i can't find the option in Administration panel to access the files